# Incompatible pointer types passing regardless of type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pointers, cgfloat

So I have the following code and on the line that is const double colorMasking[6] right now it is a double but if i clean and build it says Incompatible pointer types passing double should be float. Then however if I change it to float the error goes away but then once I clean and build again it says Incompatible pointer types passing float should be double. The exact opposite of what I just did. Any idea what is going on here?

```
-(UIImage *)changeWhiteColorTransparent: (UIImage *)image
{
    CGImageRef rawImageRef=image.CGImage;

    const double colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGImageRef maskedImageRef=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
    {
        //if in iphone
        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, image.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), maskedImageRef);
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Stupid question:  What line is flagged with that error message.

Comment: Does it work if `colorMasking` is a `CGFloat` instead of a `double`?

Comment: @HotLicks I think it is `CGImageRef maskedImageRef=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);`, since that is the only time he passes `colorMasking`.

Comment: I also wonder if it's valid to initialize a float array with ints.

Comment: Yes sorry, this is the line that throws the error 
maskedImageRef=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
and colorMasking is the value that gets changed from float to double

Comment: I get confused: On which platforms is CGFloat a `double` and on which is it `float`?

Comment: The docs provide: `CGImageRef CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors ( CGImageRef image, const CGFloat components[] );` so `colorMasking` should be of type `CGFloat`.

Comment: CGFloat worked! Thanks

Comment: @HotLicks `CGFloat` is a `float` on 32-bit systems, and a `double` on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
const double colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
```

to

```
const CGFloat colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
```

`CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` expects a `CGFloat`, which is `typedef`ed to `float` on 32-bit systems, and `double` on 64-bit.  When compiling using `float`:

1. Compiler compiles 32-bit binary and sees your `float` array, which is what the function expects.
2. Compiler compiles 64-bit binary and sees your `float` array, but the function expects a `double` array.

The opposite happens when you use `double` instead of `float`.

Here is the definition of CGFloat (in CoreGraphics/CGBase.h):

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs provide: `CGImageRef CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors ( CGImageRef image, const CGFloat components[] );` so `colorMasking` should be of type `CGFloat`.